# Mongoose query documents that include ID in array of IDs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query a list of mongodb records whose `_id`s can be found in an array of another record. For example, a user collection might include an array of liked post ids, and I want to query every user that has like a specific post.

```js
// example user model
const user = {
    name: 'user', 
    email: 'user@user.com', 
    likedPosts: [
        '111111111111',
        '222222222222',
        '333333333333'
    ]; 
}

// get all users who liked post 222222222222
const usersWhoLikePost2 = UserModel.find({
    likedPosts: ['222222222222']
});
```

But it keeps coming back as an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will only work if `likedPosts` into document have only one value (check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9WI0UZPKn6H) example) because you are telling mongo: "Give me docuemtns where `likedPosts` is an array with value `222222222222`".

You have to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to find into an array.

Something like:

```
yourModel.find({
  "likedPosts": {
    "$in": [
      "222222222222", "other values"
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zoYWFnB-J5p)

Alternatively, if you only want to search by value `222222222222` you can use the value without an array, like this.

```
yourModel.find({
  "likedPosts": "222222222222"
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DvlNhBFql2E)